# selenium get() doesn't do anything

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The code below should open a firefox browser, navigate to google and search for "automation" and should navigate again to yahoo. But driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com") doesn't do anything. How will I change URL using selenium?

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
widget=driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
widget.click();
widget.sendKeys("automation");
widget.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
widget=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui_3_12_0_1_1452245228407_940']/td[1]/a"));
widget.click();
```

Comment: You code should work. I do not see any problem. What is widget?

Comment: give some sleep after widget.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); and let me know. may be just try with Thread.sleep(6000) after this

Comment: This is right way. You can observe in browser by keeping driver.get("http://www.google.com"); and  driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com"); and commenting other code.

Comment: Try to debug, the script probably fails before you reach `driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");`

Comment: @HelpingHands, widget is WebElement.

Comment: @guy, before the second driver.get() no errors were thrown, that's why I'm wondering why get() doesn't do anything for yahoo... :(

Comment: give some sleep after widget.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); and let me know. may be just try with Thread.sleep(6000) after this - @muraliseleniumtrainer, Thread.sleep() makes it work!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same is working fine for me after pausing/stopping the my kaspersky internet security.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("seleniumhq");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Thread.sleep(6000);

driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running code on Windows, can you check your hosts file entry. You can find it in below location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Have a look at the file content and check if localhost resolution has been altered.

If it does not help, post selenium version you are using, error message which you are getting.

Comment: I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2

Answer (score -4):

You cannot open in same object. Two Options

Option 01:
You can open in new window like this

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement widget = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
widget.click();
widget.sendKeys("automation");
widget.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

WebDriver seconddriver = new FirefoxDriver();
seconddriver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Option 02:
       you can use keyboard keys to open new window or tab and then using driver.switchto.

Comment: who said ? `You cannot open in same object` For me that same code is working fine.

Comment: the question does not ask on how to open a new browser.